Hide subcategories from dropdown made with wp_dropdown_categories() -SOLVED-
Working with a wordpress plugin that uses wp_dropdown_categories() to return a dropdown.
The dropdown it returns looks like this:
<ul>
<li class="select2-results__option">Category</li>
<li class="select2-results__option">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp child-category</li>
<li class="select2-results__option">Category</li>
<li class="select2-results__option">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp child-category</li>
</ul>

I want to hide the child-categories, but cannot find a way since they all have the same class.
So my question is: can i use wp_dropdown_categories() to give child-categories a different class, then hide them with css?
I tried using jquery to hide it, but i guess the dropdown is being dynamiclly generated, so did not work.
Sorry if the issue is not clear, first time using stack overflow :)

Not sure about adding classes, but using the depth parameter it should easily be possible to get only the main categories in the first place (default is 0, which means an indefinite number of levels - setting it to 1, should only get you the main categories to begin with.) Only, you say this was in a plugin - if that's not your plugin, then you should not overwrite any of its files, otherwise those changes will be lost with the next plugin update.

Please include the arguments you sent to the function in the question. wp_dropdown_categories( $args ) What is the value of $args?

@CBroe Wow i cannot believe i overlooked that, thank you so much!
